# golang regular expression ReplaceAllString

Tags: regex, go, chatbot

I am writing a chatbot program in the Go programming language.
In this function it reads in a user string checks for a regular expression and then is supposed to remove the expression and replace with another string if found. It is successful in finding a match but will not append it to the string

```
input = "I am feeling happy"
pattern2 := []string{`.*i am.*`, `.*I AM.*`, `.*I'm.*`, `.*i'm.*`, `.*im.*`, `.*I am.*`}

// loop through pattern2 array
//if pattern is found extract substring
//set response

for _, checkPattern := range pattern2 {
    re := regexp.MustCompile(checkPattern)
    if re.MatchString(input) {
        match := re.ReplaceAllString(input, "How do you know you are $1 ?")
        response = "output : " + match
        return response
    } //if re.MatchString
} //for pattern2
```

my output for response is "how do you know you are"

my intended output "how do you know you are feeling happy"

Comment: try change your patterns to the form `.*i am(.*)`
the bracket is important as it creates a group matches $1 in your replaceAllString call.

Answer (score 3):

You can actually rewrite the regular expression to avoid having to loop. The following is an illustration of what @mypetlion is talking about:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
    input := "I AM feeling happy"
    re := regexp.MustCompile("(?i)(i[' a]*m) (.*)")
    if re.MatchString(input) {
        match := re.ReplaceAllString(input, "How do you know you are $2?")
        fmt.Println("output: " + match)
    } else {
        fmt.Println("There is no match")
    }
}
```

The expression `(?i)(i[' a]*m) (.*)` basically captures two groups of characters present in the string. The first group is the various formats of `I am`. This should work for the other variants, as well. The second matches the remaining of the string after `I am`. Please note that we are using `(?i)` to make the regular expression case-insensitive.

Once we have compiled the expression, we move on to using the matched string from ***second group*** as our replacement.

You should get the following for all variations of `I am`:

```
output: How do you know you are feeling happy?
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expressions are matching everything before and after the literals and extracting them. You need to actually capture the substring that will be used in your `re.ReplaceAllString` call. Replace the second `.*` in each expression with `(.*)`.